# How to apply Multiple Filters on video File using GPUImage Framework

Tags: ios, video, filter, gpuimage

i worked with @Brad Larson [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/tree/master/examples/iOS/SimpleVideoFileFilter) Framework. With that i am able to apply filters to video file one at a time.

But i need to implement the functionality like the user can apply the multiple filters at Once to video file. tried with different ways but no success. Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GPUImageFilterGroup or GPUImageFilterPipeline to apply multiple filter on video files. GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter is an example of GPUImageFilterGroup ([link](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/167b0389bc6e9dc4bb0121550f91d8d5d6412c53/framework/Source/GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter.m)).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i will have a try on it.

Comment: Hi Hoangdado, I have used GPUImageFilterGroup to change the filter on a live video file that is playing
`GPUImageFilterGroup *groupFilter = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc]init]; 
      [(GPUImageFilterGroup *) groupFilter setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject: filter1]];
    [(GPUImageFilterGroup *) groupFilter setTerminalFilter:filter];
     [movieFile addTarget:groupFilter];
    `
Now, i am trying to generate the video file using GPUImageMovieWriter but no Luck.
can you help me on this

Comment: Your should fix that as follow:

GPUImageFilterGroup *groupFilter = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc]init];
[groupFilter addFilter:filter1];
[groupFilter addFilter:filter];
[filter1 addTarget:filter];
[groupFilter setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject: filter1]];
[groupFilter setTerminalFilter:filter];

[movieFile addTarget:groupFilter];
[groupFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

I hope you understand the idea of filter chain.